# Codeigniter Query Num Rows

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code in a CI app :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user(user_name,user_email) VALUES(?,?)";
        $result = $this->db->query($query,array($userName,$email));
        if ($result->num_rows()>0)
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        else
            return null;
```

This yields an error ; Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cmdline\application\models\mlogin.php on line 38

line 38 is the condition for number of rows is greater than 0 . 
Now I don't get what is happening - I am using CI's documentation to check whether number of rows is greater than 0 , why does this fail ?

Comment: Has the database library been loaded?

Comment: @IanBrindley if the library wasn't loaded, the error would certainly be on the line before the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're doing an `INSERT` query. Queries that modify data return `TRUE` in all cases, so what you're really attempting is `TRUE->num_rows()`, which doesn't make any sense, causing an error.

What you actually want to check is `$this->db->affected_rows()`, which will tell you how many rows were inserted into the database.

Although you're not doing it in this case, it's worth noting that `affected_rows()` will only return the count of rows that actually changed during the query, so `UPDATE` queries that don't actually modify data (i.e. if the field already has the value the query is trying to set it to), then that row won't be reflected in the `affected_rows()` value.

Comment: yep ... that's definitely what happened here :)

Answer (score 0):

From CodeIgniter's documentation.

> The query() function returns a database result object when "read" type queries are run, which you can use to show your results. When "write" type queries are run it simply returns TRUE or FALSE depending on success or failure. When retrieving data you will typically assign the query to your own variable, like this:

Your query, because it's an INSERT will simply return TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: So what you are looking at is if($result){ return $this->db->insert_id(); }